# How to Checked my form after return with input

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4.  Here is my form

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
        <li class=""> <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" id="men" value="male" onchange="checkBoxHandler()" 
        @if (is_array(Input::has('gender')) && in_array(1, Input::has('gender'))) checked @endif
        > Men's</li>
        <li class=""><input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" id="woman" value="female" onchange="checkBoxHandler()"> Woman's</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to if input has gender->male after return it should be checked but its not working is this code is correct

```
@if(is_array(Input::has('gender')) && in_array(1, Input::has('gender'))) checked @endif
```

When i use

```
{{ dd(Input::has(gender)) }}
```

Its return true.  Help me.

Comment: post your controller that returns this form so we can see what are you doing and investigate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Your checkbox has `value='male'`, so your test should check for that, not `1` as your code has.

If you want to repopulate a form with data that the user entered previously, maybe because it failed validation, use [the `old() method`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input).

```
@if(is_array(old('gender')) && in_array('male', old('gender'))) checked @endif
```

`Input` should be used in your controllers, handling the request input, not in your views.  I think using [`$request->input('gender')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input) is the Laravel 5-ish way of accessing input.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how but this option is working fine

```
 <ul>
                <li>
                    @if(Input::has('gender'))
                    {{ Form::checkbox('gender[]',  'male', 'male', ['onchange' => 'checkBoxHandler()']) }}

                            {{ Form::label('male', ucfirst('male')) }}<br>
                      @else
                        <input type="checkbox"
                           name="gender[]"
                           id="men"
                           value="male"
                           onchange="checkBoxHandler()"
                           {{ is_array(old('gender')) && in_array('male', old('gender')) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Male
                      @endif

                </li>



                <li>
                    @if(Input::has('gender'))
                    {{ Form::checkbox('gender[]',  'female', 'female', ['onchange' => 'checkBoxHandler()']) }}

                            {{ Form::label('female', ucfirst('female')) }}<br>
                      @else
                        <input type="checkbox"
                           name="gender[]"
                           id="men"
                           value="female"
                           onchange="checkBoxHandler()"
                           {{ is_array(old('gender')) && in_array('female', old('gender')) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Female
                      @endif

                </li>

            </ul>
```